# SR3437BBB2 IC description / datasheet

Tags: identification, datasheet

Some problems with my HP StorageWorks DAT 160 USB tape storage machine. Inside among others there is a SSOP28 chip named `SR3437BBB2`. Also there is another line with symbols `7CELR5KJ G4`. It is made by Texas Instruments. Can not find any description of this chip, nor the datasheet..

Comment: Have you tried contacting TI?

Comment: Not yet, it will be last resort.. I think I found the problem already - there are two Si9986 H-Bridge drivers - which controls two motors - and input impulses are ok, but no output (DC is ok). Ordered already. It was dusty inside the mechanism - and was stuck.

Comment: So if, after a week here you don't get an answer you'll then contact TI thus wasting a week in the process of getting an answer from TI. That makes no sense.